# Thunderbird notification only in workingshours

Tags: thunderbird, notifications, time

I would like to receive thunderbird notifications only between 9 to 5, when an E-mail arrives. But I can only enable and disable it generaly under Settings -> Serverkonfiguration.  How can I archive a timeframe for this?